# Generating a list of Source Code Listings of a document

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

how I can generate a list of source code Listings like a list of Figures ??

here is an exemple of a code source Listings:

```
\lstset{
numbers=left,
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=5pt,
numberstyle=\small\color{black},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
keywordstyle=\color{black},
commentstyle=\color{black},
stringstyle=\color{black},
frame=single,
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
caption=Code coté serveur avec Express}
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1, framerule=0pt] % Start your code-block

%Code ...

\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\lstlistoflistings` prints a list of listings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\addto\captionsfrench{%
  \renewcommand*{\lstlistlistingname}{Liste des sources}%
  \renewcommand*{\lstlistingname}{Source}%
}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\lstset{
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,
  numberstyle=\small\color{black},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  keywordstyle=\color{black},
  commentstyle=\color{black},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  frame=single,
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  caption=Code coté serveur avec Express}
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1, framerule=0pt] % Start your code-block

%Code ...

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Further reading: [documentation of package `listings`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), section "4.9 Captions".

Comment: The updated answer already shows, how the names can be changed. It seems to be a text in French, thus the example even shows, how the names can be changed with `babel`.